# Unique index or primary key violation in H2 database:While inserting data into the table

Tags: spring-boot, h2

I am using h2-Db in my spring boot application, where I am getting a "Unique index or primary key violation" error while inserting data into the table.

The table creation is automatically created through the application. I am facing this insertion issue for all of my entity classes.

```
2022-07-21 07:23:58.113 ERROR 3459586 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Unique index or primary key violation: "public.username_uk1_INDEX_3 ON public.org_employee(username NULLS FIRST) VALUES ( /* 9 */ 'test' )"; SQL statement:
insert into org_employee (created_by, created_time, lock_id, modified_by, modified_time, org_code, tags, label_ids, alternate_mobile_number, application_id, auth_token, default_process_code, email, external_ref, external_ref2, failed_attempt_count, force_change_passwd, kyc_approved, kyc_id, landline_with_std, last_failed_attempt_time, last_login_time, locale, mobile_number, name, one_time_password, one_time_password_expiry, password_hash, previous_passwords, pwd_change_time, roles, self_signed_user, status, username, username_uc, whatsapp_number) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [23505-212]
2022-07-21 07:23:58.114 ERROR 3459586 --- [           main] c.e.e.service.impl.EntityServiceImpl     : Exception in saveOrUpdate 

org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:211)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractSelectingDelegate.performInsert(AbstractSelectingDelegate.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3032)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3558)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:492)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:197)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:216)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:334)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:289)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:209)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:684)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:676)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:671)
    at com.ezetap.entity.service.impl.EntityServiceImpl.saveOrUpdateInTransaction(EntityServiceImpl.java:82)
    at com.ezetap.entity.service.impl.EntityServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$5516f1da.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
    at com.ezetap.entity.service.impl.OrgEmployeeServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b5843870.saveOrUpdateInTransaction(<generated>)
    at com.ezetap.entity.service.impl.EntityServiceImpl.saveOrUpdate(EntityServiceImpl.java:57)
    at com.ezetap.entity.service.impl.OrgEmployeeServiceImpl.saveOrUpdate(OrgEmployeeServiceImpl.java:55)
    at com.ezetap.entity.service.impl.OrgEmployeeServiceImpl.saveOrUpdate(OrgEmployeeServiceImpl.java:32)
    at com.ezetap.entity.service.impl.OrgEmployeeServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$819071b.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:651)
    at com.ezetap.entity.service.impl.OrgEmployeeServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b5843870.saveOrUpdate(<generated>)
    at com.ezetap.tools.seed.loader.demo.TestOrgLoader.load(TestOrgLoader.java:74)
    at com.ezetap.tools.seed.SeedMain.load(SeedMain.java:102)
    at com.ezetap.tools.seed.SeedMain$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a0909166.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
    at com.ezetap.tools.seed.SeedMain$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2a9a840.load(<generated>)
    at com.ezetap.tools.seed.SeedMain.run(SeedMain.java:90)
    at com.ezetap.tools.seed.SeedMain$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a0909166.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:651)
    at com.ezetap.tools.seed.SeedMain$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2a9a840.run(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:806)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:790)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:777)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180)
    at com.ezetap.tools.seed.SeedMain.main(SeedMain.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:54)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Unique index or primary key violation: "public.username_uk1_INDEX_3 ON public.org_employee(username NULLS FIRST) VALUES ( /* 9 */ 'test' )"; SQL statement:
insert into org_employee (created_by, created_time, lock_id, modified_by, modified_time, org_code, tags, label_ids, alternate_mobile_number, application_id, auth_token, default_process_code, email, external_ref, external_ref2, failed_attempt_count, force_change_passwd, kyc_approved, kyc_id, landline_with_std, last_failed_attempt_time, last_login_time, locale, mobile_number, name, one_time_password, one_time_password_expiry, password_hash, previous_passwords, pwd_change_time, roles, self_signed_user, status, username, username_uc, whatsapp_number) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [23505-212]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:508)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:477)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:223)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:199)
    at org.h2.index.Index.getDuplicateKeyException(Index.java:525)
```

My entity class is:

```
@Entity
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
@Cacheable(true)
@Table(name = "org_employee", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(name = "username_uk1", columnNames = {
    "username"}), indexes = {
    @Index(name = "idx_org_code_username", columnList = "org_code,username"),
    @Index(name = "idx_org_code", columnList = "org_code"),
    @Index(name = "idx_username_uc", columnList = "username_uc"),
    @Index(name = "idx_mobile_number", columnList = "mobile_number"),
    @Index(name = "idx_whatsapp_number", columnList = "whatsapp_number")
})
public class OrgEmployee extends LabelledEntity<Long> implements IAuthEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final String ROLE_SEPARATOR = ",";
    private static final String HASH_SEPARATOR = "\\|\\|";
    private static final int MAX_PREV_PASSWORDS = 6;

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Id
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "username", length = 20, nullable = false)
    private String username;
    @Column(name = "username_uc", length = 20, nullable = false)
    private String usernameUc;
    @Column(name = "password_hash", length = 50)
    private String passwordHash;
    @Column(name = "mobile_number", length = 13)
    private String mobileNumber;
    @Column(name = "whatsapp_number", length = 13)
    private String whatsappNumber;
    @Column(name = "email", length = 50)
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "name", length = 100)
    private String name;
    @Column(length = 10)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private ActivityStatus status = ActivityStatus.ACTIVE;
    @Column(name = "default_process_code", length = 25)
    private String defaultProcessCode;
    @Column(name = "roles", length = 256)
    private String roles;
    @Column(name = "pwd_change_time")
    private Date pwdChangeTime = new Date();
    @Column(name = "failed_attempt_count")
    private int failedAttemptCount = 0;
    @Column(name = "last_failed_attempt_time")
    private Date lastFailedAttemptTime;
    @Column(name = "force_change_passwd")
    private boolean forceChangePasswd = false;
    @Column(name = "one_time_password", length = 10)
    private String oneTimePassword;
    @Column(name = "one_time_password_expiry")
    private Date oneTimePasswordExpiry;
    @Column(name = "previous_passwords", length = 310)
    private String previousPasswordHashes;
    @Column(name = "application_id", length = 64)
    private String applicationId;
    //new fields from annexure H
    @Column(name = "alternate_mobile_number", length = 13)
    private String alternateMobileNumber;
    @Column(name = "landline_with_std", length = 16)
    private String landlineNumber;

    //locale field
    @Column(name = "locale", length = 16)
    @Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.LocaleType")
    private Locale locale = Locale.ENGLISH;
    @Column(name = "auth_token", length = 32)
    private String authToken;
    @Column(name = "external_ref", length = 64)
    private String externalRef;
    @Column(name = "external_ref2", length = 64)
    private String externalRef2;
    @Column(name = "self_signed_user")
    private boolean selfSignedUser;
    @Column(name = "kyc_approved")
    private boolean kycApproved;
    @Column(name = "kyc_id", length = 64)
    private String kycId;
    @Column(name = "last_login_time")
    private Date lastLoginTime;
  

/// getter and setter

}
```

properties value for the H2 db is:

```
database.driver=org.h2.Driver
database.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/home/data/ezetap-h2;MODE=MySQL;DATABASE_TO_LOWER=TRUE;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE
database.user=root
database.password=root123 
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```